# assertthat return the message from the current function when called in a nested manner

Tags: r, assertthat

Let me explain with the help of an example.

I have two functions :

```
fun1 <- function(x) {
  assertthat::assert_that(is.numeric(x), msg = 'Not a number')
  x
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  assertthat::assert_that(x > 10, msg = 'Number not greater than 10')
  x + 10
}
```

They are called one into another.

```
fun1(x = fun2(20))
#[1] 30
```

However, if `fun2` fails, I get message from `fun1`.

```
fun1(x = fun2(2))
```

> Error: Not a number

I would expect to get message from `fun2` itself which is `'Number not greater than 10'`.

How can I get that?

I know I can break down the function calls like below which will resolve my issue.

```
y <- fun2(20)
fun1(x = y)
```

but this is a simplified example. In my real case, it is not possible to do this nor do I want to do it in that way.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of the problem is that, `assert_that()` passes the ellipsis `...` to `see_if()` and in this function the ellipsis is captured with `eval(substitute(alist(...))`. This prevents the error in `fun2` to be evaluated. The error object is returned from `fun2()` and then checked against the condition in `fun1()`, checking whether the error object `is.numeric` which it isn't so the result is as expected `'Not a number'`.

One way to avoid this is to evaluate the result of `fun2()`. In your post you have shown one way, by using an intermediate object. Another way is to evalute the result of `fun2()` early using `eval(bquote())`. Below we use `.()` inside `bquote()` to evaluate `fun2()` early before the error object that is return is captured by `see_if()`. But I guess this is not your desired solution.

```r
fun1 <- function(x) {
  eval(bquote(assertthat::assert_that(.(is.numeric(x)), msg = 'Not a number')))
  x
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  assertthat::assert_that(x > 10, msg = 'Number not greater than 10')
  x + 10
}

fun1(x = fun2(20))
#> [1] 30

fun1(x = fun2(5))
#> Error: Number not greater than 10
```

Since `assert_that` is just a drop-in replacement for `stopifnot()` the easier approach is to just use the latter - the error messages are not that bad:

```r
fun1 <- function(x) {
  stopifnot("Not a number" = is.numeric(x))
  x
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  stopifnot('Number not greater than 10' = x > 10)
  x + 10
}

fun1(x = fun2(20))
#> [1] 30

fun1(x = fun2(5))
#> Error in fun2(5): Number not greater than 10
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Yes, I ultimately decided to use `stopifnot` since it made sense here. Thank you for providing working solution with `assertthat`.